# The network path was not found when sqldatasource in aspx loads

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, connection-string, sqldatasource

I am using ASP.NET with c# and MySql, the database is on a hosting provider.I am using sqldatasource in aspx but I am getting the error below.

[image]

When my sqldatasource :

```
  <asp:SqlDataSource ID="QuotSqlDataSource" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:stockConnectionString %>" ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:stockConnectionString.ProviderName %>" 
            SelectCommand="SELECT DocNo,SalesMancode,docDate FROM docheadr where doctype='13' and docstatus='1'"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

My connection string is :

```
<add name="stockConnectionString" connectionString="Server=********;Database=*****;Uid=******;Pwd=*****;"   />
```

My connection string credentials are correct because before this page I have a login page and I connect just fine.

I notice when i remove the select command the pages load without the error.
What is I am doing wrong?

**Update 1:**
When I change my connectionstring to this I am getting this error.

```
  <add name="stockConnectionString" connectionString="Server=********;Database=*****;Uid=*******;Pwd=*******;" 
providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"   />
```

[image]

Comment: Your error says that you have an issue connecting to SQL server but you are trying to connect to MySQL so that right there is going to be an issue.  You need to setup a MySQL connection

Comment: I update my question. please have a look.Also my connection string is to connect to MySql not SQL

Comment: Show your web.config file, is there .NET MySQL provider installed? Ensure this line exist: `<add name="MySQL Data Provider" invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory,MySql.Data" />`.